# Splitting data based on time condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have rows of data that are seconds apart, however I found some anomalies. The difference between some rows is 30min or above, so I want to split my data to multiple other data frames at that condition which means loop through my data frame and split when the difference in time is above 30min. I’ve tried this already but it splits my data to one row data frame.

```
 RBD < - function(x){
    i <- 0
    while(i < length(data$Time)){
        if(data$Time[i+1]-data$Time[i] > 60*30){
            rb <- 1

        }
        else{
            rb<-0
    }
     i <- i+1
    }
}


ListData <- Data %>%
    group_by(Data$temp)%>%
    transmute(ind=all((RBD = 1))%>%
    .$ind
names(ListData) <- paste0(‘Data’, seq_along(ListData))

split(Data, ListData)
```

My Data looks like this 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwqfa.png)

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, it is better to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very helpful function in base R: `diff`, which can do the heavy lifting for you. If this doesn't work for you, try posting a [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html) and I'll see if i can help you troubleshoot.

Lets simulate some data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1200, 100)
x <- x + sample(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2400), 100, replace = TRUE)


RBD <- function(x){
    res <- lag(x) > 60*30
    res[1] <- FALSE
    res
}

RBD(x)
# [1]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   
# [13] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [25] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [37] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [49] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [73] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [85] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [97] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I did the lag function
RBD <- funtion(x){
    res <- Data$Time-lag(Data$Time) > 60*30
}
It returned TRUE when facing these specific rows 
However when I try to split my data based on that ( function's result) 
ListData <- Data %>%
    group_by(Data$temp)%>%
    transmute(ind=all((RBD = TRUE))%>%
    .$ind
It doesn't seem to work, do you have any suggestion

Comment: I want to split my data each time it faces a TRUE ( I don't want to group the "TRUE" rows)

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html) ?

Comment: I added an image of my data